# Accessing PHP web server running on a VirtualBox VM (with host-only network)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, php, webserver

I am trying to connect to the PHP built in web server (php -S) running on a VirtaulBox VM.

- My host OS: Windows 8.1 x64
- My Guest OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

I can access the Apache web server just fine, but for smaller things the PHP web server is faster and I prefer that.

The command I used to use to make such a web server is the following:

`php -S localhost:5445`

This always worked on a Linux OS. Just by typing `localhost:5445` in a browser showed the web page. However, this time when I try to access the page from the host, I get an error saying it can't connect and the log shows absolutely nothing.

In my `hosts` file, I have set up a name for the IP of the VM.

Do I need to set up anything else?

P.S.: If I can provide any more information, please tell me in a comment. :)

edit: Tried accessing the server with `localhost:5445`, `vserver:5445` and `192.168.56.56` as well, but none worked. Same error.
By the way, the error I get in Chrome is `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Comment: I think, when you say "localhost" to the server, it will only listen to loopback interface and will not be accessible from outside. Try to use it's IP-address instead, maybe, something kinda `php -S 192.168.13.37:5445`.

Comment: at8eqeq3, I answered in an edit.

Comment: You're saying about the way you try to access the server, while I'm saying about how you start it. Also, there could be a firewall on guest OS that blocks the port you use.

Comment: `php -S localhost:5445` instantiates PHP's built-in server and have it listening for requests on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1), port 5445. That's why requests coming in on the host-only adapter get refused. Try starting the server using `php -S 192.168.56.56:5445`, assuming 192.168.56.56 is the IP address of your guest OS.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. at8eqeq3, if you make an answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: @at8eqeq3 If your comment was an answer i'd give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information from the article below. Basically, you need to set firewall rules and remove the block on the port you want to use. 
I've tried this while testing symfony demo application and it works perfectly.

http://markonphp.com/use-php-built-server/